# How can an AS3 swf hosting an AS2 swf share the same array?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, localconnection

I have an AS2 swf that has an array that is updated when a user clicks on items on the screen. The array stores the currently selected items. This As2 swf is hosted by an AS3 swf loaded in using Loader class and a local connection between them is managed by swfBridge.

I want to know what the best way for both AS3 and AS2 swfs to share this array is? or how can I call a function in the AS2 (client) swf and return the array to the AS3 (host) swf when it needs to read the items from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use local connection, and grant skinner created swfBridge specifically for this purpose:

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html

if you run into any quarks with working with the arrays, I remember strange things like the length being a value in it when doing a for each loop... just a heads up.